# A question on Cramer's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Almost everybody is familiar with Cramer's theorem: a sum $X+Y$ of of independent random variables is normal if and only if both $X$ and $Y$ are normal. Are there any other classes of distributions which can replace normality in the above statement?

Comment: Another example is Raikov's theorem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem

Comment: See also [infinitely divisible distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29)

Answer (score 8):

As has been already stated, the analogous statement (I believe) is known to hold for stable distributions (I can't find a precise reference for this, but results along these lines are discussed in sections 6 and 7 of [this survey article of E. Lukacs](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200512609)).

It is also worth mentioning that there is an longstanding problem of Mark Kac which seeks to extend the spirit of these results to a more general setting. Note that we may reformulate Cramer's theorem as follows:

Theorem (Cramer)
Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be positive functions such that: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(-\xi x) d\sigma_1 (x) \times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(-\xi x) d\sigma_2(x) = e^{-\xi^2/4}.$$
Then $\sigma_1(x)$ and $\sigma_2$ are Gaussians.

Seeking to generalize this, Kac's problem is the following:

> > **(Kac's Problem)** Let $\phi(x,y) = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y} -1} $ and assume that 
> >     $$ \phi \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(-\xi x) d\sigma_1 (x), \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(-\xi x) d \sigma_2(x)\right) = \frac{1}{1+\xi^2}.$$ Is it true that $\sigma_1(x) = \alpha_1 e^{-\beta_1 |x|}$ and  $\sigma_2(x) = \alpha_2 e^{-\beta_2 |x|}$?

This is problem 178 from the [Scottish book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Book), where it is dated September 11, 1938.

Answer (score 4):

Poisson Point process in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is an example. If you have two homogeneous Poisson point processes $\Phi_X$ and $\Phi_Y$ with intensities $\lambda$ and $\mu$, their **superposition** is also a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda+\mu$. In other words, the sum of number of points of two Poisson point processes in a compact set $A$, follows Poisson law with sum of their intensity.

For the other direction, [Raikov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem) says that sum of if the sum of two independent RVs follows Poisson then each one of them should be Poisson.

Answer (score 1):

The general concept you're looking for is that of a [stable distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). See (e.g.) [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.701&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for background on discrete stable distributions.

Comment: Stable certainly gives the if.  Does it give the only if as well?